# Rails squishing on bootstrap theme on the sides

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

So I bought a bootstrap theme and was using it for a side project.  The thing is, when used in Rails, it seems to add some additional margins/paddings on the sides so that the layout becomes a bit squished.  The CSS is exactly the same so I have no idea what's causing this.  Does anyone have experience dealing with something similar?  I'm using Rails 4.0 if that makes any difference.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any CSS files other than the ones supplied by the theme loaded onto your page?  `scaffolds.css` comes immediately to mind.

Comment: Nope.  The only other file I see is application.css, which comes with the rails.

Comment: Can you post your application.css?

Comment: Figured it out.  It seems that if you disable bootstrap gem and use the one that's packaged with the purchased theme, it works.  Weird since I tried that awhile ago and it didn't really work.